# Removing characters from string

Tags: java, string, split

Say have a string:

`String x = "0: 0->1 -2.00";`

And I want to remove certain characters, specifically `:` `:` `>` and a few others so that string is now:

`0 1 -2.00`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What about a simple replace in String?

Comment: From the look of your input, you want to replace `"->"`, but not `"-"`.  Is that correct?  I may need to enhance my answer!

Comment: The long way would be to split using ":" and then join them back up again using space!

Comment: Thought of a way. Get the index of where ':' is and the index of where '>' is. then just make a StringBuilder object and remove from these. Then use toString() make it back to a String.

Answer (score 2):

To remove just one type of character, you can do this.

```
myString = myString.replace(":", "");
```

For more complicated cases, you might need a regular expression, in which case, you'll use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, but you have to be careful about escaping any characters that are "special" in a regular expression.

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("->|:", "");
```

As an example, if you wanted to remove `->` and `:` and `+`, you might write

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("->|:|\\+", "");
```

because `+` is special and needs to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: myString = myString.replaceAll("->|:|\\+", ""); is exactly what I wanted. However it will output "0 01 -2.00" not "0 1 -2.00". Any way to get rid of this extra 0 preceding the 1?

Comment: OK, how do you define which zeroes you want to remove, and which ones you don't?  What would you like `"1: 2->3 -4.00"` to become?

Comment: I guess I asked my question poorly. If I did myString = myString.replaceAll("0->|:|\\+", ""); it would remove the zero. But I want to work for a general case. Like what if the second 0 was a 3? How would I remove that as well if I didn't know what that character in the string was?

Comment: So it could be `replaceAll("\\d+->|:|\\+","")` if you wanted to remove any number from before `->`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. Also, using the same regular expression, is there a way to replace more than one space with just one? For example, if I had something like `5 4 -4.00    3  1.00` and I wanted to make it `5 4 -4.00 3 10` is there a way to do that?

Comment: Haven't tested it - but you may find that using `"\\d+->|:|\\+|\\s(?=\\s)"` as your regular expression will do the trick.

Comment: Never mind I figured out I can do something of the format `String y = x.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();` in my program to get what I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, that will work, if you want to do it in two steps.

Comment: Okay one last question, How do I add to that regular expression to make it replace anything I want? Right Now `"\\d+->|:|\\+|\\s(?=\\s)"` will replace anything that has `(any number)->` , `|` and any space greater than one. What if I want to also replace something like `(any number) to (any number) ( (any double positive or negative))`? Could you show me how to replace something like that adding on the the regular expression from before? Of course when I say `(any number)` not the actual substring "(any number)" but that meaning any number.

Comment: OK, I don't understand exactly what you're asking; but maybe its time for you to do your own research into how regular expressions work.  Start with the Javadoc for the `Pattern` class.

Comment: Basically if I have a String for example, `6 to 0 ( 0.00)    6->0  0.00` and I want `6 0 0.00`. I'll check out the java docs and see if I can figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
  x = x.replace(":", "");
  x = x.replace("->", "");
```